# Subquery parent id in NHibernate QueryOver

Tags: c#, nhibernate, subquery, queryover

I'm trying to understand how this may work.
What I would have is to have all Trees from a given list of IDs that has not rotten apples.
Looks easy but I'm fresh of NHibernate, not so good in SQL and as you can see I'm stuck.

I wrote this code down here:

```
Tree treeitem = null;

QueryOver<Apple> qapple = QueryOver.Of<Apple>()
    .Where(x => (!x.IsRotten))
    .And(Restrictions.IdEq(Projections.Property<Tree>(y => y.Id)))
    // Or this one...
    //.And(Restrictions.EqProperty(
    //     Projections.Property<Apple>(y => y.Tree.Id),
    //     Projections.Property<Tree>(y => y.Id)))
    .Select(x => x.Id);

return this.NHibernateSession.QueryOver<Tree>()
    .Where(x => x.Id.IsIn(ListOfTreeId))
    .WithSubquery.WhereExists<Apple>(qapple)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(z => z.Id).WithAlias(() => treeitem.Id)
        .Select(z => z.Name).WithAlias(() => treeitem.Name)
        .Select(z => z.Type).WithAlias(() => critem.Type)
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<Tree>())
    .List<T>();
```

And the pseudo SQL I get is something like this:

```
SELECT id, name, type FROM trees WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)
AND EXIST(SELECT id FROM apples WHERE NOT rotten AND apples.idtree = apples.id)
```

As you can see there's a problem with the subquery that use the same table Id instead of something like that:

```
EXIST(SELECT id FROM apples WHERE NOT rotten AND apples.idtree = tree.id)
```

I'm bit lost actually. Maybe there's another way to build this up.
Any help is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Im not sure why you are using resulttransformer when the return type is the same as the query type

```
return NHibernateSession.QueryOver<Tree>()
    .Where(t => t.Id.IsIn(ListOfTreeId))
    .JoinQueryOver<Apple>(t => t.Apples)
        .Where(a => !a.IsRotten)
    .List();
```

Update: the Compiler chooses `ICollection<Apple>` while it really should choose `Apple` therefor specify the generic argument in JoinQueryOver explicitly

Update2: to get them unique

opt 1)

```
...
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity());
    .List();
```

opt 2)

```
Tree treeAlias = null;

var nonRottenApples = QueryOver.Of<Apple>()
    .Where(a => !a.IsRotten)
    .Where(a => a.Tree.Id == treeAlias.Id)
    .Select(x => x.Id);   <- optional

return NHibernateSession.QueryOver(() => treeAlias)
    .Where(t => t.Id.IsIn(ListOfTreeId))
    .WithSubquery.WhereExists(nonRottenApples)
    .List();
```

Comment: About resulttransformer I followed a guide, thanks for the tip.
    .JoinQueryOver(t => t.Apples)
        .Where(a => !a.IsRotten)

the Where clause don't work because Apples is a list so a.IsRotten is not available.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works but still I have the main problem of duplicates, if for a tree I have two apples that matches criteria, I'll have the same tree twice as result.

Comment: Thank you for your time, these were are good tips. Still trying to make it work (exceptions on treeAlias.Id, property not found) but it's a good start!

Comment: Yes, Tree inherit from Model abstract whom has int Id property.

Comment: hmm, it works in a example here. Does `a => a.Tree == treeAlias` work?

Comment: Hi, yes. It's totally weird. I've to admit that nhibernate works randomly based on which tool we use: lambda, linq, criteria... it not helps a newbie.
By now I resolved switching to two lambda expression, the first one get distinct tree IDs in a List, the second make a SELECT IN. This is really bad 'cause I have two queries where one of them is also an IN (list).

Comment: Most of such unexpected behaviors i had came from gethashcode implementations and mapping errors. maybe you can post the mapping for tree